# Can I use 'ask Ubuntu' logo as my profile pic?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Is it fine if I use 'Ask Ubuntu' logo as my profile pic (my current profile pic) or is it violation of terms and conditions of this site (if exists)? I love it very much :)

Comment: As a workaround you can participate in one of the cleanups or similar event, and get a free Ask Ubuntu shirt. Then take a picture of yourself wearing it and use that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not as per the [Trademark Guidelines](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance)

Comment: Well, the latest trademark guidelines only talks about SE/SO logo... so, I'm not sure.

Comment: > This document is designed to establish guidelines for use of our names (copyright) and logos (trademarks). The "names" and "logos" discussed here refer collectively to any site or service on the Stack Exchange network and Stack Exchange Inc.